# Javascript Debugging on Client Side - IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging

Is it possible to jump over a Javascript statement (i mean without executing) in Developer Tools of Internet Explorer?

Something like "Set next statement" in Visual Studio debugger...

Answer (score 2):

Having started debugging (**F5**), you can use **F10** to step over a line.

You can set a breakpoint to stop at by clicking in the margin of the relevant line.

Answer (score 2):

As such there is no Set Next Statement but you can set a break point at the place where you want to go next and hit F5

For more details 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx